# Will scifi.SE be implemented in any way?

Tags: support

This is the first time for me on SE that a site is splitting up. For me it seems like that movies and TV used too much attention for a formerly book- and comic-based site ([scifi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)).

When this site survives beta, there will be two sites on SE for example [Once Upon a Time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/once-upon-a-time), as the new movies.SE fits much better to it, but all by-then answers are on scifi.SE.

**Will these questions on scifi.SE be implemented or will there probably be some duplicates on two SE sites?**

Comment: There has always naturally been quite some overlap between SF&F and M&TV. The general consensus is that both sites will just keep running their usual schedule, making the target of a question about a SciFi movie more or less a matter of personal preference or of the intended scope of the question. There aren't any plans to move all movie and TV stuff from SciFi.se to movies.se. That would be completely counter-intuitive and counter-productive for both sites (but especially for SciFi.se).

Comment: *"This is the first time for me on SE that a site is splitting up. For me it seems like that movies and TV used too much attention for a formerly book- and comic-based site"* - Neither was [movies.se] created as a split from [scifi.se], but as an individual site with a completely orthogonal scope, nor is it in its current form a place to dump anything movie-related and not wanted on [scifi.se].

Comment: But in fact there is already extensive material on this issue here, see: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2/49, http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/550/49, http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/938/49 and http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/376/49.

Comment: Okay. So a question like "Did event X happen in the Lord of the Ring books, too?" could be questioned on both sites?

Comment: Indeed, and if it isn't an intential cross-post by the same user (which is rather discouraged), this is absolutely not problem. As long as it doesn't concentrate solely on the books but has a connection to the movie-perspective, too, it is on-topic on both sites.

Comment: Whoops, thanks to @Napoleon Wilson. Didnt see those... dont ask me why. I'm gonna read now. :)

Comment: I'm also not sure how [movies.se] *"fits  much better"* to *Once Upon a Time* than [scifi.se]. It's a Fantasy TV-show, one is the subject matter and the other is a medium, those are completely orthogonal things, which makes both sites equally fit. Yet I also have to admit that I have far too few (if any) experience with [scifi.se] to judge if movies and TV-shows are official second class citizens there compared to books (which I hadn't the impression, though).

Answer (score 3):

This site started its public beta in December 2011, it is not a new site and has been running alongside 'Science Fiction & Fantasy' for all that duration, it is not 'splitting off'.  Hopefully the site will graduate in due course to become a full stack exchange site - but there is no intention at all to modify the scope of SciFi.  I thoroughly enjoy being a contributor to that site.

It is nearly impossible to maintain mutually exclusive scope between Stack Exchange sites.  Science Fiction Movies and TV questions are on topic here, other science Science Fiction media, such as novels, short-stories, and comics are definitely off topic.

You might ask "where should I ask Science Fiction or Fantasy questions"?  The answer depends on whether you think the question is better answered by the community here, or there, (or both).  Personally since I am passionate about developing this community, I would encourage you to post here if it is at all appropriate!